# I am losing my ubuntu share with my W10 computer and smart Tv's after any updates or restarts on the ubuntu

Tags: shared-folders

I have ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS when I build the PC and then only install samba 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.5 and then share my 3 drives across my network I can see all 3 drives on my 2 smart Tv's on my w10 computer and on a surface pro.
When I have done recent updates or have restarted the ubuntu for any reason I lose access to these files from all the devices i could access previously. When I check the share settings the share is still active and the files are still available in settings and all 3 drives have been manually mounted. I dont know what to do next

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  When you lose access to your files when it reboots, what do you do next to get the files to reappear to your Windows and Smart TV?  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285813/edit) your question and add a bit more detail.

Comment: it doesn't matter what I do on the PC whether it be an update to the base build which i have just done or jsut a restart of the ubuntu device when I log back in i will either lose the folders completely from my other devices or i can see the share path but there are no files in the folders as i have lost the share and have to reset it on the ubuntu device and even after i do this I still cannot see the ubunto device on any of my other devices

Comment: But I seem to be missing a point here when you say that this happens every time you do an update, etc.  You have not said how you get it back working.  How do you know it goes away every time you update, etc if the files are gone and you can't get them back?  My question is, what do you do after you have done this reboot to see your files again?  Do you have to do something to the server the files are on?  Do you have to do something special on the TV or client system that is trying to access them?  Or do you just continue on without files at all and guess that this happens every time?

Comment: **"When I have done recent updates or have restarted the ubuntu for any reason I lose access to these files from all the devices i could access previously."**  What steps do you take after that so you can see your files again?

Comment: Hi, I have setup the file sharing frm the ubuntu for read write access I  have on my panasonic smart tv  an option in file sharing to turn it on , once it is on the TV will see everything that is on my network automatically. the TV displays the Ubuntu as janice and i can open the file path to see 3 hdd on the device and what is on those HDD. The same on a samsung TV it automatically see's all of my devices including my panasonic tv and a surface pro and my windows 10 computer.

Comment: I have also lost Write access to all 3 of the HDD in the ubuntu box . I cna no longer save to any of these drives and or rename any of the files on teh drives

Comment: I would suggest that you open a new question about the Ubuntu installation and how you cannot write to the drives.  Please include details about what Ubuntu version it is, the hardware it is installed on, any troubleshooting steps you may have already taken.  The more details you can provide the more we may be able to help.

Comment: I fixed this issue myself